# fabric sdk connection profile adding the new organisation and installing chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am using Hyperledger fabric in one of our project. I am using fabric sdk which acts like client to Hypereledger network and server for frontend. Now

1. Lets say, I am running the fabric network with 2 organisation, and i am hosting fabric sdkjs, i will  call(middleware) which contains the connection.json to connect to hyperledger fabric network. Is it possible to add one more organisation third one to hyperledger fabric existing network. If its possible without stopping the network,do i need to update my connection.json of the middleware all the time if update the organsation. Means i need to stop the running farbric sdkjs middleware server, update connection.json then start it again.
2. Is it possible to install the chaincode to channel without been stop by hyper-ledger network.
3. Is there any support for Non fungible token ERC721 concept in hyperledger fabric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fama,

Next time if you would like to ask more than one question better ask separately in order to make it simple

**Coming to your questions**:

1) Ideally what so-called middleware (SDK App) should be per organization because you are dealing with crypto materials of a particular organization, if you planned to use one for all organizations then **yes** you have to update the latest organization details by stoping the middleware server
Some useful links for onboard nee organization https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/cl-add-an-organization-to-your-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/

2) Yes you do not need to stop consortium after you the onboard new organization you can do all operations based on policies

3) yes it has been  supporting from 1.3  in beta stage but planned to support in full production-ready only in 2.0

Announced by Swetha from IBM on October 26, 2018
https://www.hyperledger.org/blog/2018/10/26/hyperledger-fabric-now-supports-ethereum